# terminal wont stop prompting for input (homework)

Tags: linux

I am extremely new to the UNIX operating system and thus am experiencing some difficulties in my homework.

what i am trying to accomplish is using if/then statements within an alias. here is the code i have written...

```
alias getname='read filename'


alias vfile='getname; if [ ! -f $filename ]; then echo "Irregular file";'
```

I do not get errors when I source this for testing but when i run the command it does not stop prompting for input like so...

```
> 1a.out
>
>
>
>
> -bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

as you can see it will only stop when i hit control d. I don't know why it is doing this and any help provided would be greatly appreciated.

Also I am completely that using a shell function or script would be much more efficient but i am required to use an alias for the assignment.

Comment: You're missing a `fi` to your `if`:  `..."Irregular file"; fi'`

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in the comment above, you're missing a `fi` to your `if`:

```
$ type getname
getname is aliased to `read filename'

$ type vfile
vfile is aliased to `getname; if [ ! -f $filename ]; then echo "Irregular file"; fi'
```

Then:

```
$ vfile
doesNotExist
Irregular file
$ vfile
/etc/passwd
$
```